# pyinstaller exe fails - fusionscript.dll problem

Tags: python, pyinstaller

[Thanks to Charles Duffy for the gentle nudging toward a clearer question! I am new to Stack Overflow and appreciate the help. After more research, it appears that the dependent code is actually within Blackmagic's fusionscript.dll code (If the .dll is missing, my exe is able to continue past the line of my code which tries to import) , so I don't see any way to get around it until they update.]

Original question:

I'm stuck trying to get a pyinstaller executable to work on a Windows 10 test system. My exe works fine on a system that has Python 3.6.8 installed.

Complete code is below. The print command that starts with "trying:" succeeds and shows the correct path for the import. The print command immediately after the import command *print("Made it past import")* is not executed, and the exe quits without showing any errors.

I've determined that there's just one file that is necessary for the exe to run on the test system, and that's the os.py file in the Lib folder of the Python install. Without that file, the exe just quits (without any error message) when it hits the line of code: *script_module = imp.load_dynamic("fusionscript", path + "fusionscript" + ext)*

For anyone trying to reproduce: the exe runs when a Python 3.6.8 install is present, or more specifically, when os.py is. I made the installer with a simple *pyinstaller importTest.py* command. I place the fusionscipt.dll in the folder with the resulting executable. If os.py is present, the exe runs normally and prints all of it's print commands. If you remove os.py from the Python Lib directory, this is no longer the case, and the exe quits when it hits the imp command.

NOTE: I know that imp is deprecated, but the API that my code engages with (fusionscript.dll for Resolve) only works with Python 3.6, so I can't use anything newer.

---

Here's the code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
import sys
import imp
import os
CURR_DIR = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(CURR_DIR)
script_module = None
ext = ".dll"
path = CURR_DIR+"\\"
try:
    print("trying: " + path + "fusionscript" + ext)
    script_module = imp.load_dynamic("fusionscript", path + "fusionscript" + ext)
    print("Made it past import")
except ImportError:
    pass
print("script module = ",script_module)
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: There is no error message at all. There is the result of a print statement from the line immediately before the problematic line, then the exe quits with no further output. "Traceback" does not appear.

Comment: there is no answer for this problem if you don't show code which makes problem - If we can't run it then we can't say what can make problem.

Comment: Complete code now in question.

Comment: (BTW, I've had a rough time trying to get Fusion 17.1's Python bindings working myself -- though that was back while it was in beta and the documentation wasn't yet updated; would want to take another look now that it's released; that said, this was Fusion-in-general, not Fusion+pyinstaller -- you're adding together two separate sources of complexity going that route).

Comment: Anyhow -- in this case, a [mre] consists not just of your program (ideally, a version cut down to the shortest version that can produce the problem when run without changes -- so removing all the non-Windows-specific code, f/e), but details of how you're bundling it with pyinstaller.

Comment: Upon further research, I've figured out that the problem is not with my code, but with BlackMagic's fusionscript.dll code, which seems to be dependent on a Python install (specifically os.py in the python path) on the host system, even if it's being imported by an exe that has Python and all the necessary modules included.